Cannot connect ClickHouse to DBeaver
I'm trying to connect my ClickHouse Server to DBeaver and I'm getting this error:

We didn't encountered this problem when we're trying to connect other database such as mariadb and vertica.
How could we solve this connection problem?
The server is already running and we have downloaded the latest JDBC drivers from the official ClickHouse github repo: https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-java/releases/

We wanted to connect our server to DBeaver for our organisation.

which port do you use for connection? 8123 or 9000? use 8123 for HTTP or 8443 with sslmode=1 for  HTTP over TLS
